# Implementing collection of objects with search method

Tags: php, data-structures

I was wondering if are existing implementations for collection of objects with build in support in search methods such as binary search.
We are talking about php.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is already a php library which covers probably the most details from  your question : http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php

This library offers structures like **Doubly Linked Lists**, **Heaps** etc.